# Do SQLite objects retain it's ID even if an item before it is deleted?

Tags: sqlite, django-views

I need to work with the id's of the items in my SQLite database but the id's leave holes in the numbering if an item is deleted.

Comment: What's the question? There's nothing wrong with that, in fact, you'd be in serious trouble if numbers changed. Imagine what would happen in a parent-child relation if you deleted #50 out of 100 items. Suddenly, 49 parent records would end up with different children. 49 orders would suddenly contain different items

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I see what you are saying, but if for some reason i had say 1 000 000 items, would that not then be problematic if it didn't reuse the id's of deleted items instead of leaving gaps?

Comment: Read this: https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html

Comment: No, it won't be problematic at all. 1M rows is small data for a database server even if it may be a lot of data for an embedded database like SQLite. 1M can be handled by a 32-bit integer key. You'd have to reach 4B keys before you had to consider using a 64-bit integer. If anything, mixing up 1M IDs is *far worse* than mixing up 50 IDs.